# trying to create script that scan for secrets in python code

Tags: python, passwords, key

As part of our CI/CD we want to add some check to run code on python files and check if there are some secrets in code (like API, passwords etc.).
I saw only programs that do this, and I want to create a Python script that does it.

Does anyone have some suggestion or example for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it exactly what you look for but you can use GitGuardian API,

> The GitGuardian API puts at your fingertips the power to detect more
> than 200 types of secrets in any text content, as well as other
> potential security vulnerabilities.
>
> py-gitguardian can be used to create integrations to scan various data
> sources, from your workstation's filesystem to your favorite chat
> application.

You can check API details [here](https://api.gitguardian.com/docs) with all the response codes and expected structures on each method.

just take a look [GitGuardian/py-gitguardian](https://github.com/GitGuardian/py-gitguardian) Github repository,
You can also check this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYPG_9IwxJE) that will help you implement this.

Good luck.